# I need to build a php script that upload or get a file from Google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I followed the quickstart sample http://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php but is a 2 steps operation, i'd like to have a simple script that get automatically the authorization code without a second step, my script should be a function without a user interaction.

Anybody has a simple sample ?

Answer (score 0):

THis is impossible. [OAuth2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31) is a multi step operation and **needs** user interaction, at least the first time your app try to access this user's Drive.